# Using camera to analyze garage door status

Tags: c#, image-processing, computer-vision, emgucv

I got the idea to use images from my IP camera, to register if my garage door is open or closed (or maybe even somewhere in between).
I figured it would be simple to put some identifiable markers on the door, and then "read" their position programatic, but I have no experince in image processing, and therefore no idea what it's called.
After a lot of reading, my guess is that I need to use Emgu CV in some way (I'm coding in C#).

Can someone point me in the right direction to get started?
What is the right method for what I am trying to achieve? Blob tracking?

Comment: Dont try to find any complicated or fancy-named algorithms for simple problems ;) I assume your cam is in a fixed position relative to the door. Shoot an image with opened and one with closed door. Compare them visually. Find a region in your image where the images differ the most, e.g. if your door is white the floor inside your garage is gray simply itereate over a few hundred (depending on your camera resolution) pixels in the image, average their brightnesses and check if it is above a threshold (->white, door closed) or below (door open). Of course choose a region that is always visible.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas I will definitely try that as the first solution and see if it suffice :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is old but I happen to have done exactly this recently.

I have an old smartphone from which I can remotely enable the LED flash + take a picture and download it. I attached a shiny reflector on a specific location of the garage door and the smartphone is drilled to the wall.

I implemented in python. I download the picture over HTTP, and after a few attempts I identified where to crop the full picture. Then I compute the brightness, which tend to indicate a valid detection above 150 (it's usually 200 when the reflector is here, 130 when it's not but lights on, and 10 when the reflector is not here and lights are off).

```
def loadFromCam(url):
    print("GET " + baseUrl + url)
    return requests.get(baseUrl + url, timeout=(10,10))

def brightness(im):
    stat = ImageStat.Stat(im)
    return stat.rms[0]

def loadImage():
    response = loadFromCam("cam/1/frame.jpg")
    f = open(destination + 'frame.jpg', 'wb')
    f.write(response.content)
    f.close()
    return Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))

def cropImage(img):
    left = 365
    top = 400
    right = 410
    bottom = 435

    return img.crop((left, top, right, bottom))

def toggleLed():
    loadFromCam("cam/1/led_toggle")
```

and then how it's used:

```
toggleLed()
time.sleep(0.1)
image = loadImage()
toggleLed()

crop = cropImage(image)
crop.save(destination + "crop.jpg")
print("brightness:", brightness(crop))
```

The result is two files (full picture and crop), and the brightness amount.

Note: I just started Python so this may be ugly or not the recommended practice